# "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type" after ejecting from CRA

Tags: jsx, create-react-app, babel-loader

I have created a React app using `npx create-react-app <packageName>` and then ejected the configurations and dependencies using `npm run eject`.

On running `npm run bundle` (where bundle is defined in my script as `"bundle": "webpack -w --mode=development"`), I get the below error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 8:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| ReactDOM.render(
>   <React.StrictMode>
|     <App />
|   </React.StrictMode>,
```

I have babel configured to parse and load jsx but still the error says "need appropriate loader".

Here is what my package.json looks like:

```
 {
  "name": "handisure",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.12.3",
    "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "0.4.2",
    "@svgr/webpack": "5.4.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.7",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^10.0.0",
    "bfj": "^7.0.2",
    "camelcase": "^6.1.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.3.0",
    "css-loader": "4.3.0",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "5.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.11.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^3.9.2",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "6.1.1",
    "fs-extra": "^9.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.5.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "26.6.0",
    "jest-circus": "26.6.0",
    "jest-resolve": "26.6.0",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.6.1",
    "prompts": "2.4.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^11.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-refresh": "^0.8.3",
    "resolve": "1.18.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "sass-loader": "8.0.2",
    "semver": "7.3.2",
    "style-loader": "1.3.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "4.2.3",
    "ts-pnp": "1.2.0",
    "url-loader": "4.1.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4",
    "webpack": "4.44.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "5.1.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js",
    "bundle": "webpack -w --mode=development"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is what my webpack.config.js looks like:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (webpackEnv) {
  const isEnvDevelopment = webpackEnv === 'development';
  const isEnvProduction = webpackEnv === 'production';
  const isEnvProductionProfile =
    isEnvProduction && process.argv.includes('--profile');
  const env = getClientEnvironment(paths.publicUrlOrPath.slice(0, -1));
  const shouldUseReactRefresh = env.raw.FAST_REFRESH;
  const getStyleLoaders = (cssOptions, preProcessor) => {
    const loaders = [
      isEnvDevelopment && require.resolve('style-loader'),
      isEnvProduction && {
        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        options: paths.publicUrlOrPath.startsWith('.')
          ? { publicPath: '../../' }
          : {},
      },
      {
        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
        options: cssOptions,
      },
      {
        loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
        options: {
          ident: 'postcss',
          plugins: () => [
            require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
            require('postcss-preset-env')({
              autoprefixer: {
                flexbox: 'no-2009',
              },
              stage: 3,
            }),
            postcssNormalize(),
          ],
          sourceMap: isEnvProduction ? shouldUseSourceMap : isEnvDevelopment,
        },
      },
    ].filter(Boolean);
    if (preProcessor) {
      loaders.push(
        {
          loader: require.resolve('resolve-url-loader'),
          options: {
            sourceMap: isEnvProduction ? shouldUseSourceMap : isEnvDevelopment,
            root: paths.appSrc,
          },
        },
        {
          loader: require.resolve(preProcessor),
          options: {
            sourceMap: true,
          },
        }
      );
    }
    return loaders;
  };

  return {
    mode: isEnvProduction ? 'production' : isEnvDevelopment && 'development',
    bail: isEnvProduction,
    devtool: isEnvProduction
      ? shouldUseSourceMap
        ? 'source-map'
        : false
      : isEnvDevelopment && 'cheap-module-source-map',
    entry:
      isEnvDevelopment && !shouldUseReactRefresh
        ? [
            webpackDevClientEntry,
            paths.appIndexJs,
          ]
        : paths.appIndexJs,
    output: {
      path: isEnvProduction ? paths.appBuild : undefined,
      pathinfo: isEnvDevelopment,
      filename: isEnvProduction
        ? 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js'
        : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/bundle.js',
      futureEmitAssets: true,
      chunkFilename: isEnvProduction
        ? 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.js'
        : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
      publicPath: paths.publicUrlOrPath,
      devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: isEnvProduction
        ? info =>
            path
              .relative(paths.appSrc, info.absoluteResourcePath)
              .replace(/\\/g, '/')
        : isEnvDevelopment &&
          (info => path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/')),
      // are used on the same page.
      jsonpFunction: `webpackJsonp${appPackageJson.name}`,
      globalObject: 'this',
    },
    optimization: {
      minimize: isEnvProduction,
      minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({
          terserOptions: {
            parse: {
              ecma: 8,
            },
            compress: {
              ecma: 5,
              warnings: false,
              comparisons: false,
              inline: 2,
            },
            mangle: {
              safari10: true,
            },
            keep_classnames: isEnvProductionProfile,
            keep_fnames: isEnvProductionProfile,
            output: {
              ecma: 5,
              comments: false,
              ascii_only: true,
            },
          },
          sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
        }),
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
          cssProcessorOptions: {
            parser: safePostCssParser,
            map: shouldUseSourceMap
              ? {
                  inline: false,
                  annotation: true,
                }
              : false,
          },
          cssProcessorPluginOptions: {
            preset: ['default', { minifyFontValues: { removeQuotes: false } }],
          },
        }),
      ],
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        name: false,
      },
      runtimeChunk: {
        name: entrypoint => `runtime-${entrypoint.name}`,
      },
    },
    resolve: {
      modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
        modules.additionalModulePaths || []
      ),
      extensions: paths.moduleFileExtensions
        .map(ext => `.${ext}`)
        .filter(ext => useTypeScript || !ext.includes('ts')),
      alias: {
        'react-native': 'react-native-web',
        ...(isEnvProductionProfile && {
          'react-dom$': 'react-dom/profiling',
          'scheduler/tracing': 'scheduler/tracing-profiling',
        }),
        ...(modules.webpackAliases || {}),
      },
      plugins: [
        PnpWebpackPlugin,
        new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [
          paths.appPackageJson,
          reactRefreshOverlayEntry,
        ]),
      ],
    },
    resolveLoader: {
      plugins: [
        PnpWebpackPlugin.moduleLoader(module),
      ],
    },
    module: {
      strictExportPresence: true,
      rules: [
        { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },
        {
          oneOf: [
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
              include: paths.appSrc,
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                customize: require.resolve(
                  'babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides'
                ),
                presets: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app'),
                    {
                      runtime: hasJsxRuntime ? 'automatic' : 'classic',
                    },
                  ],
                ],
                
                plugins: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-plugin-named-asset-import'),
                    {
                      loaderMap: {
                        svg: {
                          ReactComponent:
                            '@svgr/webpack?-svgo,+titleProp,+ref![path]',
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                  isEnvDevelopment &&
                    shouldUseReactRefresh &&
                    require.resolve('react-refresh/babel'),
                ].filter(Boolean),
                cacheDirectory: true,
                cacheCompression: false,
                compact: isEnvProduction,
              },
            },
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
              exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                babelrc: false,
                configFile: false,
                compact: false,
                presets: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'),
                    { helpers: true },
                  ],
                ],
                cacheDirectory: true,
                cacheCompression: false,
                
                sourceMaps: shouldUseSourceMap,
                inputSourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
              },
            },
            {
              loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
              exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
              options: {
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  };
};
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: hi @ Priyanka Masne, did you find any solution for it ?